# How to limit the number of sub column in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a data like

```
{
 u'_id': {u'$oid': u'548e8396f7e19418857e47fc'},
 u'a': [
     {u'd': u'a'},
     {u'd': u'a'},
     ...,
     {u'd': u'a'}
 ]
}
```

I wonder how do I limit the number of sub column like

> {u'_id': {u'$oid': u'548e8396f7e19418857e47fc'},  u'a': [{u'd': u'a'},
>   {u'd': u'a'}, {u'd': u'a'}] }

For the entire document, I can do it using

> db.Col.find().limit(5)

But how to extract several sub column at each document?

Comment: If you need to limit the array elements, you need to perform an aggregation operation to unwind the array first, and then limit the required number of documents, again group the documents based on the `_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator.

The syntax you are looking for is something like this:

```
db.your_collection.find({
   ...
}, {
   your_field: { $slice: 3 }
});
```

this should return you 3 first subelements from your array (you can use -3 to return last)