# MongoDB PHP Limit the returning values of a field

Tags: php, mongodb, field, limit

```
{
    name : "name 1",
    field : [
        {
            random:"value 1",
            random2:"second value"
        }
        {
            random:"value 2",
            random2:"second value 2"
        }
        {
            random:"value 3",
            random2:"second value 3"
        }
        {
            random:"value 4",
            random2:"second value 4"
        }
    ]
}
{
    name : "name 2",
    field : [
        {
            random:"value 5",
            random2:"second value"
        }
        {
            random:"value 6",
            random2:"second value 6"
        }
        {
            random:"value 7",
            random2:"second value 7"
        }
        {
            random:"value 8",
            random2:"second value 8"
        }
        {
            random:"value 9",
            random2:"second value 9"
        }
    ]
}
```

i have a collection like this. what i want to do is, when i query this collection, i want only first 2 arrays of the field to return.

expected return:

```
{
    name : "name 1",
    field : [
        {
            random:"value 1",
            random2:"second value"
        }
        {
            random:"value 2",
            random2:"second value 2"
        }
    ]
}
{
    name : "name 2",
    field : [
        {
            random:"value 5",
            random2:"second value"
        }
        {
            random:"value 6",
            random2:"second value 6"
        }
    ]
}
```

i've checked [Query Modifiers](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-modifier/) but they are sorting/limiting the documents, not fields in the documents.

So how can i accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to limit the number of sub column in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575734/how-to-limit-the-number-of-sub-column-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator to limit the number of items of an array that a query returns:

```
db.collection.find({}, {"name": 1, "field": { "$slice": 2}})
```